# Looking for a reference to munin single-letter prefixes

Tags: munin, graph

I am looking for a reference to what the prefixes shown in the munin graphs mean, e.g., `m`, `u`, `k`, etc. I can guess several, but it would be helpful to have a complete list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = milli
u = micro (though it should really be a Mu character: μ)
k = kilo
...
```

[Complete list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), courtesy of Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the individual plugin that generated the graph, and the graph should include information about whether the unit is request per second, response time, number of reads/writes (io) or whatever it might be.

The type for the data value in the munin plugin can be of different types. You can read about them at the Munin documentation [here](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins#DERIVEvs.COUNTER) and [here](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/protocol-config)

The four types of datasources are COUNTER, ABSOLUTE, DERIVE and GAUGE. With a default to GAUGE.

Comment: I think I misled you. I did not mean "units" but, rather, the single-letter prefixes that munin uses (e.g., `m`, `k`, etc.). I have edited the question to be clarify this point.